# reloading the .asoundrc file without rebooting

Tags: raspberry-pi, alsa

I want to reload the .asoundrc file to switch between hdmi and the 3.5mm jack.

I'm able to switch between the two by software which switches the content of .asoundrc, but it only switches my sound output after I play a new file or reboot the system.

I've tried the following to reload the file.

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Which returns: sudo: alsa: command not found

```
sudo /etc/init.d/alsa-utils stop
sudo alsactl kill rescan
sudo /etc/init.d/alsa-utils start
```

Doesnt return an error, but doesn't work either

Comment: The .asoundrc file is read when the PCM device is opened. You have to restart whatever program is actually opening the device (PulseAudio?).